# Schwa insertion into the bi-consonantal onset for emphasis?

Tags: pronunciation

I want to know if American English speakers have regional differences in inserting the schwa between initial consonants of words such as great, crazy, professional, and crash for emphasis. For a case in point, Americans that are born and raised in Maryland do not insert the schwa for emphasis whereas Americans that are born and raised in Los Angeles CA and Texas do insert the schwa for that purpose in the plosive and liquid clusters.

E.g. (1) Gareat! /gə'ret/
and   (2) Carazy! /kə'rezi/

Comment: I don't understand the question. you seem to know that peple do it for emphasis. What else do you need to know?

Comment: It’s not biconsonantal onset: it’s stop-plus-liquid onset ***PUH-LEASE!*** :)

Comment: I think the OP wants to know whether this is regional, or whether it occurs throughout North American English.

Comment: Interesting anacoluthon.

Comment: I don't know if Tony the Tiger promotes *Kelloggs Sugar Frosties* in the US (where I do know they're called [*Frosted Flakes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frosted_Flakes)). But the voiceover in the British ads is typically British, and we don't enunciate our **r**'s anywhere near as much as Americans. So *our* Tony says *"They're **g ə ə ə 'reat!**"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It’s not just you. ***Everybody’s*** Tony says that!

Comment: @tchrist: But I bet the American Tony rolls his **r**'s more!

Comment: I remember Tony from when _I_ was a kid. I'm surprised he can still speak, never mind roll r's.

Comment: It is an issue of whether the transition between g/k and r is open or close transition (in terms of Catford). The so-called shadow vowel (or schwa) between g/k and r shows an open transition. Similarly, when preachers add a shadow schwa after voiced consonants (like Goda for God, Jesusa for Jesus). In unmarked contexts, native speakers don't add these shadow vowels. The so-called half-devoicing for final voiced consonants is the same: if you voice after release, you end up with a shadow vowel (schwa); if  you release after devoicing, people don't hear the shadow vowel.

Comment: Oh Hideo wherefore art though with your amazingly interesting questions! This question is  g ə ə ə 'reat for a first question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take: the schwa is inserted into words that begin (as tchrist already mentioned) with a stop and a glide.  I've heard this insertion most often when someone is shouting a word, whether to be heard or for emphasis.  It's a feature of over-the-top delivery, like what you'd hear from a carnival barker, a street vendor, a revival preacher.  I've heard this in dialogue on TV shows and movies, and not necessarily in the context of regional diction.

In short: it's probably not regional, just contextual.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was born in Los Angeles, raised in Orange County and I don't know what you're talking about.  I can't recall anyone I know speaking in this manner.  For emphasis?  Can't recall that, either.

I've lived with Southern folks (Georgia), Canucks (Ontario), and am acquainted with Brit-origin Canucks (Victoria, BC), and lived for nearly 3 years in England and I've hardly every heard this schwa stuff.  Not as a matter of normal everyday speech anyway.